# SimpleXMLElement Object to session

Tags: php, xml, session, xml-parsing, session-variables

```
print_r($arrayresult['applicationid']);

$_SESSION['appid']=$arrayresult['applicationid'];
```

output:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 37170 )
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception '`Exception`' with message 'Serialization of '`SimpleXMLElement`' is not allowed' in [no active file] on line 0

i'm not able to put 37170 into session variable

Comment: explicitly cast it to a string `$_SESSION['appid']=(string)$arrayresult['applicationid'];`

Comment: <?php
session_start();
$var=$_SESSION['appid'];
echo $var;?> ERROR:Undefined index: appid. i tried to access the session variable in different page

Comment: are you starting the session on the page that is making the assignment.

Comment: yes starting the session in both file.

Comment: Thank you !! your suggestion is working fine i made some mistake in form action !!!!!